# How Render Partial view from JS in Layout

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

Trying to use JS to render a partial view based on the URL... This is almost working but I can't use Razor syntax in the PathRoot Var so I tried escaping it but then it doesn't render... Any Ideas would be greatly appreciated.

```html
<head>
  <script>
            var SiteUrl = window.location.hostname;            
            var FloodlightPathRoot = '@@Html.Partial("~/Views/shared/FloodlightTags/' ; 
            var FloodlightEnd = '");';
            switch (SiteUrl) {
                case "www.website.com":
                    var FloodlightFilePath = "first.cshtml";
                    break;
                case "www.website2.com":
                    var FloodlightFilePath = "second.cshtml";
                    break;
            }
            var FloodFull = (FloodlightPathRoot + FloodlightFilePath + FloodlightEnd);
            $('head').append(FloodFull);
    </script>
</head>
```

It writes the razor syntax to the head but the page has already rendered. Can I render the razor syntax after the head is updated?

```html
<head>
@Html.Partial("~/Views/shared/FloodlightTags/first.cshtml");
</head>
```

Comment: `if (....) { @Html.Partial("...first.cshtml") } else { @Html.Partial("...second.cshtml") }`

Comment: I had tried that but both were rendering at the same time in the source

Comment: Impossible - an `if` block will only generate one or the other.

Answer (score 0):

in addition to Stephen's answer you can do it like this:

```
@{
    var url = new Uri(new Uri(this.Context.Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority)), Url.Content("~/")).ToString();
    if (url == "http://www.website.com/")
    {
        @Html.Partial("~/Views/shared/FloodlightTags/first.cshtml");
    }
    else if (url == "http://www.website2.com/")
    {
        @Html.Partial("~/Views/shared/FloodlightTags/second.cshtml");
    }
}
```

`var url` will get the site `url` and then it will check weather it matches `http://www.website.com/` if so it will render `first.cshtml` else it will check the second condition.

Comment: @MarioAntoci welcome to StackOverflow if any answer helps you can accept the answer, if you dont know how you can check this  [how-does-accepting-an-answer-work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 0):

While using your code it can done this way

```
 <head>
   <script>
    @{
        string path = Request.RequestUri.PathAndQuery;
        if (path.Contains("www.website.com"))
        {
            @Html.Partial("~/Views/shared/FloodlightTags/first.cshtml");
        }
        else if (path.Contains("www.website.com"))
        {
            @Html.Partial("~/Views/shared/FloodlightTags/second.cshtml");
        }
    }
</script>
</head>
```